# linked list delete node after root

Tags: c, linked-list

I am doing an exercise at linked lists and I came across a problem. The linked list is a tail so I want to delete the element that is in the 1st place upside the root node. I **don't** want to delete the root node in any case. The code is:

```
struct goods {
    char* section;
    char* pname;
    int value;
    int customer_num;
    int cash;
    struct goods* next;
};

void delete_goods(int customer_num, struct goods* root) {
    struct goods *current = root;
    struct goods *previous = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->customer_num == customer_num) {
            if (previous == NULL) {
                current = current->next;
                free(root);
            } else {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);
                current = previous->next;
            }
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct goods));
    root->next = NULL;
    printf("give the number of starting customers\n");
    scanf("%d", &customers);
    inform_list(customers);     // adds element to list



    else if (r == 'r' && customers != 0) {
        printf("removing...\n");
        delete_goods(customers, root);
        customers -= 1;
        printf("customers:\t%d\n", customers);
        print();
    }
}
```

I didn't post the whole code (It includes some functions for adding elements to link list for your convenience I can do it if you like. I need to way to fix my delete function so it satisfies the demands I stated above.
Here a sample output of the list:
`customers:    2
customer:   2
item value: 32
product name:   asdasd
customer:   1
item value: 43
product name:   sdsad
customer:   0
item value: 0
product name:   (null)`
 what I need is my delete function to remove customer 1 if asked then customer 2 etc.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the root node "in any case" perhaps starting your traversal at `current = root->next` and `previous = root` would be worth considering. Just saying. That, assuming `root` is properly tested for NULL in the first place (never say never). And given your restriction, I'm pressed to see why `free(root);` is present *anywhere* in this code.

Comment: thanks Whoz. the reason this statement`if (previous==NULL){
       current=current->next;
       free(root);
     } `  exist in my code is that i couldn't remove without making my delete function crashing

Comment: Yeah...    I fear that your cunning plan of doing an obviously wrong thing to prevent another wrong thing from happening is Baldrick-worthy:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you want to preserve the root node, so you want to start from `root->next` (i.e. `root` will always be non-null).

This should work [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
delete_goods(int customer_num, struct goods *root)
{
    struct goods *current = root->next;
    struct goods *previous = NULL;
    struct goods *next;

    for (;  current != NULL;  current = next) {
        next = current->next;

        if (current->customer_num == customer_num) {
            if (previous != NULL)
                previous->next = next;
            else
                root->next = next;

            free(current);
        }
        else
            previous = current;
    }
}
```

Here's a slightly more compact version:

```
void
delete_goods(int customer_num, struct goods *root)
{
    struct goods *current = root->next;
    struct goods *previous = root;
    struct goods *next;

    for (;  current != NULL;  current = next) {
        next = current->next;

        if (current->customer_num == customer_num) {
            previous->next = next;
            free(current);
        }
        else
            previous = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Craig

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that the technique of introducing the `next` variable to simplify the logic became clear [and why it's needed].